# Kafka partitioning in SpringBoot

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, micronaut

I am new in Kafka. I need to write a simple producer and consumer for Kafka by Spring Boot.Actually I am moving from micronaut to Spring Boot. I have a problem with partitioning of the topic. In micronaut, I use @KafkaKey for the partition key as below:

```
public void process(@KafkaKey MyKey kafkaKey, @Body MyRecord myRecord)
```

When it comes to spring, I do not know how to do it because as I see KafkaTemplete class has partition parameter as an Integer object.

```
public ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> send(String topic, Integer partition, K key, @Nullable V data)
```

So how can I perform the first line in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KafkaTemplate has different methods for sending messages. For example:

1. Send the data to the provided topic with the provided key and no partition

`send(java.lang.String topic, K key, V data)`

2. Send the data to the provided topic with no key or partition.

`end(java.lang.String topic, V data)`

You can choose most suitable way here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I was confused with partitioning and concept of key.

Comment: Similarly how can I take this key parameter in KafkaListener ?

Comment: Something like `@KafkaListener(id = "qux", topicPattern = "myTopic1")
public void listen(@Payload String foo,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) Integer key,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
    ...
}`